# changing from dropdown menu to mutli select open box

Tags: php, loops, drop-down-menu, foreach, superglobals

I have a drop down menu that I want to change to a multiple select box. The code below is working if you only select 1 option (the way I had it before), but of you select 2 it will only show 1 of the two, how can I make it show both options selected, here is the code:

```
<?php $makes = array("volvo","Saab","Opel","Audi","BMW") ?>


<form method="post" name="store" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" >
<select multiple="multiple" name="cars">
<?php foreach ($makes as $make){echo "<option value=\"$make\">". $make ."</option>";           $vehicles = $_POST['cars'];} ?>
    <input name="submit" type="submit">
    </select>
</form>
<?php 


if($_POST['submit']){
  echo $vehicles;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't completely clear from your question but I think you mean the following bit of code only echoes one value:

```
if($_POST['submit']){
  echo $vehicles;
}
```

To turn your selected cars into an array you need to add `[]` onto the end of the name:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="cars[]">
```

Then to `echo` each of the selections you can use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($_POST['cars'] as $car)
    echo $car.'<br />';
```

Comment: i think you are on the right track, thank you very much, but i am getting an error when trying your code:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: i forgot this part:   
    name="cars[]"

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I hope I read this correctly that you would like to retrieve an array of results from the HTML multi select box.

By the way your code snippit is not correct; the HTML <form> closing tag should be after your closing <select> tag and I'm not sure why you have the following in your PHP for() loop:

```
$vehicles = $_POST['cars'];
```

You will want to make the HTML  tags' name attribute an array as follows (Note I did not test this code):

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="cars[]">
<?php 
    foreach ($makes as $make) {
        echo "<option value=\"$make\">". $make ."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>

<?php 
    if($_POST['submit']) {
        print_r($_POST['cars']);
     }
?>
```

[PHP.net - How do I get all the results from a select multiple HTML tag?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.select-multiple)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with  if($_POST['submit']){
    print_r($vehicles);
}
please let me know if any issue then..